# Resetting a variable to 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this little bit of code that I can't quite work correctly.   The part giving me trouble is this:

```
IF( Class_Subset = @prevSub AND RegNum = @prevNum AND `DRI` >99.99 ,
@Platinum :=@Platinum + 1 ,''  )
```

What I need to do is tell the `@Platinum` to reset back to `zero` once the `Class_Subset`, or `RegNum` conditions are no longer met.

Any ideas?

Whole code:

```
SELECT  
 Harley.Hgt, Harley.RegNum, Harley.Callname, Harley.OLastname,  
 Harley.Tpe, Harley.Points, Harley.Class, Harley.Total_Points,  
 Harley.Title, Harley.Platinum, Harley.Silver_Purple,  
 Harley.Date_Earned, Harley.Judge, Harley.HostClub, Harley.DRI,  
 Harley.Class_Subset, Harley.IncorrectRegNum, Harley.MemNum, Harley.ID
FROM
 (
   SELECT
    Hgt, RegNum, Callname, OLastname, Tpe, Points, Class,  
    Total_Points, Title, Silver_Purple, Date_Earned, Judge,  
    HostClub, DRI, Class_Subset, IncorrectRegNum, MemNum, ID, 
    IF (
     Class_Subset = @prevSub  
     AND RegNum = @prevNum  
     AND `DRI` > 99.99,  
     @Platinum := @Platinum + 1,  
     0
    ) AS Platinum,  
    @prevSub := Class_Subset,  
    @prevNum := RegNum
   FROM  
    Harley,  
    (  
      SELECT @Platinum := 0, @prevSub := '', @prevNum := ''  
    ) r  
   ORDER BY RegNum, Class_Subset, Date_Earned  
 ) Harley
```

This is what the file looks like,  you can see why it needs to remember the variable while the RegNum and Subset match, but then reset to 0 once they change:

[sample data http://nadacforum.com/Platinum.png](http://nadacforum.com/Platinum.png)

Comment: Do you want to return the value from the expression, or just assign zero to the variable? Are you using this in a query or a function/procedure?

Comment: While RegNum and Subset match I want the variable to stay active, but then once either one of those change I want it to reset back to zero.   This is in a query

Comment: @ChrisNelson capture output of `if` usnig `into @Platinum`. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I now see the issue.

The row set where `Platinum` is being calculated is ordered by `RegNum` and `Class_Subset` (in particular), which is fine as the calculation does rely on those columns being sorted. But the `IF()` condition also involves the `DRI` column, and, as can be seen on your screenshot, a sequence of `DRI` values greater than `99.99` may be interrupted within a single group of `(RegNum, Class_Subset)`. When it is reinstated, you need the Platinum values to carry on, *not* to reset to `1`.

Therefore, your `@Platinum` expression should be a bit more sophisticated. Here's one way of changing it:

```
@Platinum := IF (
 Class_Subset = @prevSub  
 AND RegNum = @prevNum  
 AND `DRI` > 99.99,
 @Platinum,  
 0
) + (`DRI` > 99.99) AS Platinum,
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be looking for:

```
if(
    Class_Subset = @prevSub 
    AND RegNum = @prevNum 
    AND `DRI` >99.99,
    @Platinum + 1,
    0
) into @Platinum
```

With the above change, your query may look like:

```
select /* some fields here, */ if ( ...as above... from ...
```

Comment: No dice.  It works perfect for the first class, but then once it gets to a new one the variable doesn't reset.  So the end total for the first class is 43, and then the next one should start at 1, but it's 44.   I attached the whole query above in case I mistook something